# My Column Formatting No Longer Works (and the problem seems to only be on my computer...)

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, column-formatting

I have a column that is a Risk Index that calculates based on other columns. The equation calculates as following:

- -50
- 0
- 30
- 70
- 100

-50 = Pending Review / 0 = Completed, no risk / 30 = Risk Mitigated / 70 = Working through Risks / 100 = OH NO FIRE FIRE FIRE

This is my JSON Formatting:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "padding": "10px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField < '0', 'sp-field-severity--low',if(@currentField < '20', 'sp-field-severity--good', if(@currentField < '40', 'ms-bgColor-themeLighter', if(@currentField <= '70', 'sp-field-severity--warning', 'sp-field-severity--blocked'))) + ' ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary'"
  },
  "customCardProps": {
    "openOnEvent": "hover",
    "directionalHint": "rightCenter",
    "isBreakVisible": false,
    "formatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "font-size": "12px",
        "display": "block",
        "margin-left": "auto",
        "margin-right": "auto",
        "width": "180px",
        "padding": "4px"
      },
      "txtContent": "[$Overall_x0020_Risk_x0020_Summary]"
    }
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 6px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(@currentField < '0', 'HourGlass',if(@currentField < '20', 'CheckMark', if(@currentField < '40', 'MultiSelect', if(@currentField <= '70', 'WarningSolid', 'WarningSolid')))"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "=if(@currentField < '0', 'Incomplete',if(@currentField < '20', 'No Risk', if(@currentField < '40', 'Risk Acceptable', if(@currentField <= '70', 'Med. Risk', 'Attention Required',)))"
    }
  ]
}
```

It was working fine until today, when suddenly, anything ranking at 100 is showing as "**No Risk**"... calculation is working fine, it is definitely rated at **100** but it is being formatted as if it was **0**.

I checked with colleagues, and it seems only **MY** computer seems to be the issue. I've reset my views, I cleared my  cache, tried FireFox and Edge but for whatever reason, it's still formatting incorrectly **only** for me. Perhaps for others as well. What's going on?

WITH FORMATTING:

[image: with formatting]

WITHOUT FORMATTING

[image: without formatting]

Comment: Could you edit your question and paste a screenshot of the column without the format and a screenshot with the format? Thanks!

Comment: I can see few syntax errors like: one `)` is missing in expressions for `class`, `iconName`, `txtContent`, etc. Also, there is one extra `,` at the end of last `if` block in expression for `txtContent` property.

Comment: @theChrisKent - done! But now that I've done it, I've asked colleagues to send me screenshots as well - the formatting works for them perfectly. Not for me, and not for meaccross chrome / firefox / edge...even after clearing cookies.

Comment: Try converting the field using the `Number()` function in your conditional expressions and use numbers instead of strings. (e.g: `if(Number(@currentField) < 0, 'sp-field-severity--low...'`)